# How to determine the maximum of the following function?

Tags: calculus, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Assume $B,C \in \mathbb{C}^{5 \times  5}$ are Hermitian matrices, and $B,C \ge 0$, then we want to calculate
$$
\max_{x \in \mathbb{C}^5} \frac{\left\langle Cx,x \right\rangle}{\left\langle (I+B)x,x \right\rangle},
$$
and the answer tells me that it equals to the largest eigenvalue of the Hermitian matrix
$$
(I+B)^{-1/2} C (I+B)^{-1/2},
$$
but how can I check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\langle (I + B)x,x\rangle = \langle (I + B)^{1/2}x, (I + B)^{1/2}x \rangle.
$$
With the substitution $y = (I + B)^{1/2}x$, we have
$$
\max_{x \in \mathbb{C}^5} \frac{\left\langle Cx,x \right\rangle}{\left\langle (I+B)x,x \right\rangle} = 
\max_{x \in \mathbb{C}^5}\frac{\langle C(I + B)^{-1/2}y,(I + B)^{-1/2}y\rangle}{\langle y,y \rangle}
\\= \max_{x \in \Bbb C^5} \frac{\langle (I+B)^{-1/2}C(I + B)^{-1/2}y,y\rangle}{\langle y,y \rangle}.
$$
By the Rayleigh-Ritz theorem, this maximum is the largest eigenvalue of $(I+B)^{-1/2}C(I + B)^{-1/2}$.